# Update local branch from merge conflicts resolved in the Github UI

Tags: git, github, merge

I resolved some merge conflicts on the Github UI, but my local files are not showing these changes after a `git pull` or a `git fetch`.

How do you update your local files to reflect merge conflicts resolved on the Github UI?

Answer (score 0):

From "[Resolving a merge conflict on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github), make sure you have clicked on:

- "`Mark as resolved.`" when you are done resolving a conflict.
- " Commit merge" when you have resolved all conflcits

Without that step, there would be no new merge commit done, which means no new commit for you to pull or fetch.

And look for the right branch:

> When you resolve a merge conflict on GitHub, the entire base branch of your pull request is merged into the head branch, even if the head branch is the default branch of your repository, like master, or a protected branch. Make sure you really want to commit to this branch.